# Excel VBA - Insert Multiple Columns at a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert multiple columns at the range. Below code inserts 1 column at a range stored in variable "startCELL".

```
Range(startCELL).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
```

I can insert as many columns I want by repeating below code e.g. if I need 3 columns I can do that by repeating this code 3 times.

**Is there a way to insert multiple columns at a specific range using single line of code?**

Thanks - I am new learner so I don't know this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Resize`:

```
Range(startCELL).Offset(,1).Resize(,3).EntireColumn.Insert
```

Comment: I suspect startCELL to be a string.

Comment: @Excelosaurus - probably, and it's probably better that it's not.

Comment: @BigBen I cant believe I did'nt think of resize. And yes it is a string so have to use "Range" with it to work but this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For the case to insert a column at the left of only specified cells,

- original cells (need to insert in front of B3, C3, D3 at once)

[image]

- after insertion

[image]

- code

```vb
Sub fixColumn()
    Dim idx As Integer, cellStr As String
    With activeSheet
        For idx = 2 To 4
            cellStr = cellStr & .Cells(3, idx).Address(False, False) & ","
        Next
        cellStr = left(cellStr, Len(cellStr) - 1)
        .Range(cellStr).Select
        Selection.EntireColumn.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End With
End Sub
```